# validation errors are added only in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am stuck on a problem related to validation. However, validation errors are present only in production environment and do not make sense.

Details: upon submitting a form via AJAX creating a new `stop` instance, I get back Stop#new due to failure of @stop.save in Stop#create action. Errors that are preventing stop saving are caused by

1. lack of `Setup` (Setup Must Exist) - stop `belongs_to` Setup, but
   there is no validation rule checking for presence of parent setup
2. lack of `User ended` (User Ended Must Exist) - stop `belongs_to` user_ended, but again there is no validation rule to enforce user_ended presence

I am not able to replicate same errors in development env, in which app is accepting new stop without validation errors.

Anybody can point me to possible reasons of this? I am trying to think of something to debug in production environment, and any suggestion on this are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, maybe you are using Rails 5, if thats is the case all `belongs_to` associations are required by default. To opt-out of this you should declare it like this:

```
belongs_to :setup, optional: true
belongs_to :user_ended, optional: true
```

Comment: Yes, I am using RoR 5.1.4 Thanks for this tip, however I am still curious why in development not all `belongs_to` relations are validated for presence?

Comment: Maybe your development environment has a different version.

Comment: Of course not. Same RoR and rubies in both enviroments.

Answer (score 1):

I did an incremental upgrade from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.1.4 and also had this issue of the development environment not picking up the require in the `belongs_to` associations by default (although the production environment did).  Looking at the initializer files, I realized I hadn't gone through the `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb` and flipped the new defaults per the suggestion in the file.  The `belongs_to_required_by_default` flag was set to false in this file.  Flipping this flag to true (or removing the file altogether as it was no longer needed) solved this problem, and my development environment now required the `belongs_to` associations. However, I'm still unclear why the production environment was not respecting the flag set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I searched release notes and discovered that in rails 5.0

> `belongs_to` will now trigger a validation error by default if the
>   association is not present. You can turn this off on a per-association
>   basis with `optional: true`. Also deprecate `required` option in favor of
>   optional for `belongs_to`.

Additionally, rake task for updating to version 5.0 of rails is adding the following option

> # Require `belongs_to` associations by default. Previous versions had false.
>   `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default
>   = false`

However, rails 5.1 stopped to use this option without any warning, Rails team decided that documenting this change only in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) of `belongs_to` association should be enough. More in the [issue #18937](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937)